# Get current page number of DataPager

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-3.5

I'm trying to get the page number for the current page of my ListView. I'm using a DataPager component with the following code:

```
int CurrentPage = ((DataPager1.StartRowIndex) / DataPager1.MaximumRows) + 1;
```

to try and get the page number of the when it loads i.e. when the user navigates through pages, however what happens is that DataPager1.StartRowIndex returns the index of the previous page rather than the new page, and as a result, my page count is calculated incorrectly.

In the case above - MaximumRows = 15. I'm expecting StartRowIndex to equal 0 on the first page, therefore (0/15)+1 would give me a page number of 1. On page 2 I would expect StartRowIndex to equal 15, and therefore the current page number to be 2.

---

To provide further information:

I'm using a listview component -

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvQuals" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsListQual" 
OnItemDataBound="lvQuals_ItemDataBound" 
OnPagePropertiesChanged="lvQuals_PagePropertiesChanged">
```

With the following code behind -

```
public void lvQuals_PagePropertiesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ToggleArchivedLink();
}

protected void ToggleArchivedLink()
{
   int CurrentPage = ((DataPager1.StartRowIndex) / DataPager1.MaximumRows) + 1;
```

DataPager1.StartRowIndex at times hows the correct page index, but other times shows the index for the previos page.

Comment: `StartRowIndex` indicates the index of the first record that is displayed the page. I'm afraid your problem is something else.

Comment: can you provide some samples values for StartRowIndex, MaximumRows, CurrentPage and what you are expecting CurrentPage to be?

Comment: @ShaiCohen updated the post with an example

Comment: Your calculations look correct. What value **are** you getting for StartRowIndex for the first page?

Comment: in which part of your code you are trying to get the value of `StartRowIndex` ? because it is probably not updated with the new values yet, and thats why you get old values. You can try DataPager.PreRender event where the values are new.

Answer (score 3):

It maybe *when* you are trying to calculate the current page number. Your code does not indicate where you are doing this, but the correct place is during the `PagePropertiesChanging` event of the *ListView*. Like so:

```
protected void ListView_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender,PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)    
{
    int CurrentPage = ((DataPager1.StartRowIndex) / DataPager1.MaximumRows) + 1;
}
```

And then bind to the event like so:

```
<asp:ListView ... OnPagePropertiesChanging="ListView_PagePropertiesChanging" ... >
```

Comment: I've tried calling it on the Page_Load event and the ListView_PagePropertiesChanging event, and both outcomes are the same

Comment: What value are you getting for StartRowIndex for the first page?

Comment: I'm getting 0 for the first page, and 0 for the second page

Comment: That's strange. Honestly, I am at a loss here. I am not sure how to proceed. The only thing I can suggest, if you are willing, is to create a new project with only that functionality. This way you can isolate what the issue may be. In my experience, situations like these, where everything looks like it should be working, end up being caused by something we never expect. Please keep me updated on your progress.

Comment: I've just tried using the StartRowIndex method on the listview too, and I get the following error message: 'ListView.StartRowIndex' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Can you put both the aspx ListView code and the code-behind StartRowIndex code in your original question? That would make it easier to figure out what is happening. Also, other people can see it and try to help.

Comment: Nope. I anticipate revisiting it again next week. It's still is causing issues. :S

Comment: Fixed it finally. It was down to an incorrectly used assignment on a different part of the page. I created a copy of the project and slowly stripped away bits till it worked. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out! How hard did you hit yourself when you discovered what the issue was? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think following link will help you doing this.

http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2011/09/08/paging-listview-using-datapager-without-using-datasource-control.aspx

and

https://web.archive.org/web/20211029044137/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010610-1.aspx